# After changing the password, should logout application from all devices where logged in before in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I am working on a Spring Boot web application. There is a feature to change old password to new password for logged in users. So I want that if a user is logged in into web application through desktop and through other devices too. In other words, a user is logged in into web app through multiple devices. And if that user changes his/her password from web app then must be logged out from all other devices too automatically.

So how should I achieve this kind of security for my web app using Spring Boot? Please provide me your helpful suggestions.

Comment: Can you please provide some code of your actual implementation? It would be helpful to give you better suggestions

Comment: I did not code anything yet. I am just trying to get some idea to implement this thing in my project.

Comment: This question can not be answered in its current state as the implementation is dependant on what type of login and session tracking technology is used.

Comment: Mostly, I will use HttpSession. May be.

Comment: Rakhi just to make it clear: when you say you'll use HttpSession, you mean that the login process will update the http session (using cookies) and set an expiration date for it? If so, @Bhushan Unyal's answer should do it

Answer (score -1):

First Register HttpSessionEventPublisher :

```
@Bean
public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() { //(5)
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

Configure custome WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter imple where we will register SessionRegistry :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(....)               
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(..)    
            .others details        
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()) // Register sessionRegistry
        ;
    }

     @Bean
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {         
            return new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }
}
```

Now your logout logic will :

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

public void logoutUserFromAllSessions(String username) {
    for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
        if (principal instanceof User) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
            if (userDetails.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                for (SessionInformation information : sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(userDetails, true)) {
                    information.expireNow();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes the user is using session cookies. The question has not disclosed how the session is tracked. Downvoted.

Comment: @Bhushan Uniyal, can you suggest an approach when JWT authorization is used?

Comment: @Toerktumlare as she mentioned spring web, so its come with default httpsession not jwt, also if you will read her chat thread on question she mentioned httpsession. down vote not making any sense here :(

Comment: @mnagdev jwt need token store strategy with whitelisting concept. you can use aerospike or redis cache for performance